# iOS manual testing on Testdroid

Tags: ios, manual-testing, testdroid

I just wanted to know if I can do manual testing of iOS (.ipa) app on Tesdroid. As in upload the .ipa and install it on a cloud iPhone to perform manual testing?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, iOS manual testing is supported in Bitbar Testing (Testdroid). iOS Manual testing was introduced during end of year 2016 and currently it's supported with dedicated devices and Private/Enterprise installations.

For more information http://docs.bitbar.com/testing/user-manuals/manual-testing/ or http://bitbar.com/testing/solutions/public-cloud/

Answer (score 4):

**EDIT::**
Yes, manual testing of iOS app is supported on the Testdroid platform. This was introduced during the end of 2016. Please refer https://bitbar.com/ios-app-testing/

Answer (score -2):

You can not doing the ios app testing on testdroid. if you want to test ios app then you can use the appium on mac.

Comment: Kindly update your answer as Testdroid started supporting iOS manual testing sometime after you posted your answer. Or you can delete it as it will attract downvotes in the current state.